# Do I have to manually create the combined folder when using Python's Minimatic module?

Tags: python, pylons

I'm using the Python library Minimatic found at this site:  [Minimatic](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/Minimatic/1.0)

What this essentially does is it minifies and combines all your css and js files into one file.  When deploying my Pylons web application on the server, does this mean I have to manually create the combined folders?  So if I have the the directory as such:

```
/public
|
|--/combined
   |
   |-/js
   |-/css
|
|--/css
|--/js
```

In /`public/css` and `/public/js`, this is where I store all my regular uncompressed css and js.  In `/public/combined/js` and `/public/combined/css`, that's where I specify the combined property for JS and CSS files in my python code.  Do I need to manually create the combined directories in my server or will Minimatic create them for me?

Thanks
-Mark

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, Minimatic will, as of this writing, create the directories for you.  I found this out by [reading the source code on GitHub](http://github.com/kaukas/Minimatic/blob/master/minimatic/__init__.py) - lines 149 to 166 or so have your answer.